# Detect if device auto orientation mode turned on or off in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I'm working on this app that uses a video player. In here I use 2 main options to change the orientation of the player, which are the fullscreen button, and the auto rotation feature (changes according to device orientation). For this I'm using 2 libraries,
[Auto orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_orientation)   and

[Native device orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation)

The functionality works perfectly fine, when the device auto rotation mode is turned on. But it misbehaves when it is turned off. I know how to fix this issue. But can't find a suitable library for this.

**So basically what I need is, I want to run a specific set of code on the condition , if the device's auto orientation mode turnes on/off. So are there any flutter libraries available to check the auto rotation status? Basically I need to detect whether it is turned on or off.**
Any help would be highly appreciated :)

PS: I didn't add any code, because it's not the code I need help with. Thanks

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation You can refer this.

Comment: Hi @KrishBhanushali. Thanks for the reply. But I don't want a way to rotate the screen. I just want to detect if the device's auto rotation mode is on or off. Hope you get it.

Comment: Sorry from my side. I didn't find any library but if you really want to do it you can call method channels and use System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this, although it doesn't look like it's been updated in a while:

[auto_rotate_get](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_rotate_get)

On Android it uses this:

```
Settings.System.getInt(activity?.contentResolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1
```

I don't think it supports iOS.

Comment: Yep, iOS has `false` flag set by default without any implementation. But I think since iOS 16 release it is now impossible due to `shouldAutoRotate` deprecation.